# recursive search of File Extension in File

Tags: python, recursion

I have a file which can include another file. I need to  open the include file and determine the file extension of the specific file (demo.spx). For example:

File Name : sample.txt

```
* SetUp Time Simulation

*****************************************************
*Options
.options nomod
*+  autostop=0
*+  rmax=2
*+  absv=1E-6
*+  relv=1E-3
*+  trtol=0.1
*+  lvltim=3
*+  dvdt=2
*+  relvar=0.2
*+  absvar=0.2
*+  ft=0.2
*+  relmos=0.01
*+  method=TRAP
*+  notop=0
+  post=1
+  runlvl=5  rmax=25
+  ingold=2
+  CO=132
+  MEASFORM = 3
.WIDTH OUT=132


.include './test.sp'
```

> File : test.sp

```
 *****************************************************

* Circuit definition
.include **'demo.spx'**

.param vdd=0.99
.param vss=0
.temp=-40C

*Supplies
.global VDD VSS VBP VBN
Vdd  VDD 0 vdd
Vss  VSS 0 vss
Vbp  VBP 0 vdd
Vbn  VBN 0 0
Vsi  SI  0 0
Vse  SE  0 0
```

I have written the following code but it looks like I am doing some mistake. So first I checked that I have formatted if into first file and found that return. If I do not have that I look into file which is included and try to look into second File. We need to recursive search upto two times.
**Second version of code**

> I have modified code again and able to determine file extension on
>   First Level But Second Level I am not able to determine File Extension
>   which return me None. Review comment also welcome if I can improve my
>   code

```
#!/usr/bin/env py

import os
import sys
def parse_file_extension(gold_deck, found, count):
    extention_list = [ "lvs", "cir", "spx"]
    if( count == 2 or found == True):
        return
    with open(gold_deck, 'r+') as fspi:
        while 1:
            data = fspi.readline()
            if not data:
                break
            if data.startswith('.include'):
                data = data.split()
                print data
                netlist_file_extension = data[1].split(".")[-1].rstrip("'")
                print netlist_file_extension
                if netlist_file_extension in extention_list:
                    netlist_file = os.path.basename(data[1]).strip("'")
                    count = count + 1
                    found = True
                    print "First include"
                    print count
                    return netlist_file
                else:
                    gold_deck = os.path.basename(data[1]).rstrip("'")
                    print gold_deck
                    parse_file_extension(gold_deck, found, count)

def main(argv):
    gold_deck = "sample.txt"
    netlist_file = parse_file_extension(gold_deck, False, 0)
    print netlist_file  **//None Expecting demo.spx**

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to refactor your work according to this considerations:

- I used **open** and **close** to read file : it adds one line but limit the cyclomatic complexity (which helps for understanding it)
- I removed the **Found** value, which didn't do anything (at least in your final code)
- I renamed the **count** parameter to **depth**, and increment it before calling it instead of inside function

I then have few remarks about your last code solution:

- it does not check the depth, so won't stop after 2 cycles
- the return statement will break the loop whenever a line starts with **.include**, so it won't cover files with multiple includes

I hope this can help.

```
#!/usr/bin/env py

from os.path import splitext
import sys

def parse_file_extension(gold_deck, depth):
    extention_list = [ "lvs", "cir", "spx"]
    fspi = open(gold_deck, 'r+')
    for data in fspi:
        if data.startswith('.include'):
            data = data.split()
            netlist_file,netlist_file_extension = splitext(data[1].strip("'"))
            if netlist_file_extension not in extention_list:
                netlist_file = parse_file_extension(netlist_file, depth+1)
            return netlist_file
    fspi.close()

def main(argv):
    gold_deck = "sample.txt"
    netlist_file = parse_file_extension(gold_deck, 0)
    print netlist_file

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
                return netlist_file
```

with

```
                yield netlist_file
```

So your function returns iterator.

```
  files=[parse_file_extension(gold_deck, found, count)]
```

will produce list of files.

Answer (score 0):

After my analysis, I have fixed this issue into First level and second level search with below code implementation.It will be great help if anyone provide code commnet/optimization in below code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env py

import os
import sys

def parse_file_extension(gold_deck, found, count):
    extention_list = [ "lvs", "cir", "spx"]
    with open(gold_deck, 'r+') as fspi:
        while 1:
            data = fspi.readline()
            if not data:
                break
            if data.startswith('.include'):
                data = data.split()
                netlist_file_extension = data[1].split(".")[-1].strip("'")
                count = count + 1
                if netlist_file_extension in extention_list:
                    found = True
                    netlist_file = os.path.basename(data[1]).strip("'")
                    return netlist_file
                else:
                    gold_deck = os.path.basename(data[1]).strip("'")
                    netlist_file = parse_file_extension(gold_deck, found, count)
                    return netlist_file

def main(argv):
    gold_deck = "sample.txt"
    #gold_deck = "test.sp"
    netlist_file = parse_file_extension(gold_deck, False, 0)
    print netlist_file

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Comment: You should update your original question with this code or ask another separate question. Generally you shouldn't try to ask follow-up questions by "answering" your own question.